# Add a 'point zero' to first level of nested css counter

Tags: html, css

Here's the ordered list I have so far:

```
1 Item
2 Item
    2.1 Item
    2.2 Item
    2.3 Item
        2.3.1 Item
        2.3.2 Item
        2.3.3 Item
3 Item
4 Item
```

This is produced by the following:

```
<ol>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item
    <ol>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item
        <ol>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
        </ol></li>
    </ol></li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
</ol>
```

and the CSS:

```
ol {
    counter-reset:section;
    list-style-type: none;
}

li:before {
    counter-increment: section;
    content: counters(section, ".") " ";
}
```

What I want to do is make the top level list items have a 'point zero' following the counter, as in

```
1.0 Item
2.0 Item
    2.1 Item
```

and so forth. Can this be done in CSS? It may need a creative solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the initial styling to include the `0`.

```
ol {
    counter-reset: section;
    list-style-type: none;
}
li:before {
    counter-increment: section;
    content: counters(section, ".")".0 ";
}
```

Overwrite that by selecting the children elements.

```
li > ol > li:before {
    content: counters(section, ".")" ";
}
```

```css
ol {
    counter-reset: section;
    list-style-type: none;
}
li:before {
    counter-increment: section;
    content: counters(section, ".")".0 ";
}
li > ol > li:before {
    content: counters(section, ".")" ";
}
```

```html
<ol>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item
        <ol>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item
                <ol>
                    <li>Item</li>
                    <li>Item</li>
                    <li>Item</li>
                </ol>
            </li>
        </ol>
    </li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Sir, you are a genius. I would accept it right now, but I have to wait a few minutes. Thank you!

Comment: `(+1)`, You've earned it! Great Thinking.